# Dynamically invoke WCF Service from its URI (http://ip:port/Service1.svc?WSDL)

Tags: wcf, class, proxy, dynamic, invoke

So here it is:

I am trying to invoke a WCF Service's method from with in a windows form client application. I do not have the Contract Class Definition. The only thing I have is the Service's URI, which is http://ip:port/Service1.svc.

So I thought i could make a proxy class for that. I want to make the proxy class at run time so any external tool to create a proxy class and import to project can't help me.

I managed to make the proxy class on the fly. Here's the code:

```
        Dim mexClient As MetadataExchangeClient = New MetadataExchangeClient(New Uri(webServicesWSDLUrl), MetadataExchangeClientMode.HttpGet)
        mexClient.ResolveMetadataReferences = True
        Dim metaDocs As MetadataSet = mexClient.GetMetadata()

        Dim importer As WsdlImporter = New WsdlImporter(metaDocs)
        Dim generator As ServiceContractGenerator = New ServiceContractGenerator()

        Dim dataContractImporter As New Object
        Dim xsdDCImporter As XsdDataContractImporter
        If (Not importer.State.TryGetValue(GetType(XsdDataContractImporter), dataContractImporter)) Then

            Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find the XsdDataContractImporter! Adding custom importer.")
            xsdDCImporter = New XsdDataContractImporter()
            xsdDCImporter.Options = New ImportOptions()
            importer.State.Add(GetType(XsdDataContractImporter), xsdDCImporter)

        Else

            xsdDCImporter = TryCast(dataContractImporter, XsdDataContractImporter)
            If (xsdDCImporter.Options Is Nothing) Then

                Console.WriteLine("There were no ImportOptions on the importer.")
                xsdDCImporter.Options = New ImportOptions()
            End If

        End If

        Dim exts As System.Collections.IEnumerable = importer.WsdlImportExtensions
        Dim newExts As New System.Collections.Generic.List(Of IWsdlImportExtension)
        For Each ext As IWsdlImportExtension In exts
            Console.WriteLine("Default WSDL import extensions: {0}", ext.GetType().Name)
            newExts.Add(ext)
        Next

        Dim polExts As System.Collections.IEnumerable = importer.PolicyImportExtensions
        importer = New WsdlImporter(metaDocs, polExts, newExts)


        Dim Contracts As System.Collections.ObjectModel.Collection(Of ContractDescription) = importer.ImportAllContracts()
        importer.ImportAllEndpoints()
        importer.ImportAllBindings()



        For Each contract As ContractDescription In Contracts
            generator.GenerateServiceContractType(contract)
        Next


        If generator.Errors.Count <> 0 Then
            Throw New Exception("There were errors during code compilation.")
        End If


        Dim nmspace As CodeNamespace = New CodeNamespace()
        Dim unit1 As CodeCompileUnit = New CodeCompileUnit()
        unit1.Namespaces.Add(nmspace)


        Dim CodeDomProvider As System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider = System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CreateProvider("VB")

        Dim assemblyReferences() As String
        assemblyReferences = New String() {"System.dll", _
            "System.Web.Services.dll", "System.Web.dll", _
            "System.Xml.dll", "System.Data.dll"}
        Dim parms As CompilerParameters = New CompilerParameters(assemblyReferences)
        parms.GenerateInMemory = True '(Thanks for this line nikolas)

        'CompilerRsults
        results = CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromDom(parms, generator.TargetCompileUnit)
```

Now using the `results` I make an Instance of my WebService (`methodName = "GetData"`, `args = new Object() { 4 }` ): See Below..

```
        Dim wsvcClass As Object = results.CompiledAssembly.CreateInstance(serviceName)
        Dim retValue As Object = wsvcClass.GetType().InvokeMember(methodName, BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, Nothing, wsvcClass, args)
```

The last command throws an Exception

```
    A first chance exception of type 'System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
System.ServiceModel.EndpointNotFoundException: There was no endpoint listening at http://ip:port/Service1.svc that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details. ---> System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---

Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelUtilities.ProcessGetResponseWebException(WebException webException, HttpWebRequest request, HttpAbortReason abortReason)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestChannel.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ReA first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in ThirdPartyAPIClientApp.exe
questChannelBinder.Request(Message message, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   at System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   at IService1.GetData(Int32 value)
   at Service1Client.GetData(Int32 value)
```

Below You can find the web.config of the Web Service and the App.config of the client application

> web.config

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>

  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" strict="false" explicit="true" targetFramework="4.0" />
  </system.web>

  <system.diagnostics>
    <sources>
      <source name="System.ServiceModel.MessageLogging">
        <listeners>
          <add name="messages"
          type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener"
          initializeData="c:\logs\messages.svclog" />
        </listeners>
      </source>
    </sources>
  </system.diagnostics>

  <system.serviceModel>

    <diagnostics>
      <messageLogging
           logEntireMessage="true"
           logMalformedMessages="false"
           logMessagesAtServiceLevel="true"
           logMessagesAtTransportLevel="false"
           maxMessagesToLog="3000"
           maxSizeOfMessageToLog="2000"/>
    </diagnostics>

    <services>
      <!-- Note: the service name must match the configuration name for the service implementation. -->
      <service name="WcfService1.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_This" >
        <endpoint address="/Service1.svc" contract="WcfService1.IService1" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingNamespace="http://ip:port/WCF1_Test" />
        <endpoint contract="IMetadataExchange" binding="mexHttpBinding" address="mex" />
      </service>
    </services>


    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="BasicHttpBinding_This">
          <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>

    <bindings>


      <basicHttpBinding>

        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_This" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
          openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
          bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
          maxBufferPoolSize="200000000000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000000000"
          messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
          allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="2147483647"
            maxArrayLength="2147483647" maxBytesPerRead="2147483647" maxNameTableCharCount="2147483647" />

          <security mode="None">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
              realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
  </system.serviceModel>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
  </system.webServer>

</configuration>
```

> App.config

```
 <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0"/>
    </startup>

    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings>
          <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_This" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
              openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
              bypassProxyOnLocal="false"  hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
              maxBufferPoolSize="200000000" maxReceivedMessageSize="200000000"
              messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
              allowCookies="false">
              <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="200000000"
                maxArrayLength="200000000" maxBytesPerRead="200000000" maxNameTableCharCount="200000000" />

              <security mode="None">
                <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                  realm="" />
                <message clientCredentialType="UserName" algorithmSuite="Default" />
              </security>
            </binding>
          </basicHttpBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>

          <endpoint address="http://ip:port/Service1.svc"
                binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_This"
                contract="IService1" name="BasicHttpBinding_This" />

        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Additionally I am sending the contract and the code class of the WebService

> Contract

```
    <ServiceContract(Namespace:="http://ip:port/WCF1_Test")>
    Public Interface IService1

    <OperationContract(isOneway:=False)>
    Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String

    <OperationContract(isOneway:=False)>
    Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType

    ' TODO: Add your service operations here

End Interface

' Use a data contract as illustrated in the sample below to add composite types to service operations.

<DataContract()>
Public Class CompositeType

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property BoolValue() As Boolean

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property StringValue() As String

End Class
```

> Code Class

```
    <ServiceBehavior(Namespace:="http://ip:port/WCF1_Test")>
Public Class Service1
    Implements IService1

    Public Sub New()
    End Sub

    Public Function GetData(ByVal value As Integer) As String Implements IService1.GetData
        Return String.Format("You entered: {0}", value)
    End Function

    Public Function GetDataUsingDataContract(ByVal composite As CompositeType) As CompositeType Implements IService1.GetDataUsingDataContract
        If composite Is Nothing Then
            Throw New ArgumentNullException("composite")
        End If
        If composite.BoolValue Then
            composite.StringValue &= "Suffix"
        End If
        Return composite
    End Function

End Class
```

Does any one knows the solution? What is the proper way to invoke a WCF method Dynamically if someone only knows the URI?
 PS: the Web Service is Up and Running on an IIS7

Comment: There is a whole tutorial on Code project - Dynamically Generate a WCF Proxy. That seems to cover what you want to do:

Comment: Thanks Preet.. But in the general solution i do not have any access to the referred web service... Only its URI, as i have mentioned...

Comment: @Ermis: Then how do you know how to call it, what data to pass in as arguments, what data to expect back, what binding it uses, what the security requirements are, etc? Please explain your scenario and needs in greater detail.

Comment: Allon i want to make a mechanism to automatically register client's web services to my system in order for me to be able to call any method i want having the name of that method. (lets say the methods are Subs and take no parameters). I am currently trying using BasicHttpBinding and i don't care about security at this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So guys the above procedure works. It makes an assemply on the fly and then uses that to run methods. The think is now that I want to call a CompositeType from the assemply, but this is a different scenario. For primitive types of parameters/return values, for BasicHttpBinding and WCF Web Services, the above works. (The problem was that I had an error in my web.config file, that i didn't copy on the post)

Comment: If you only have the url of the service and you are calling the WCF service method through code (using reflection), how did u manage to get the config information (app.config)? I need help with this.